# Collection view cell content is layering

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

My button labels are stacked/regenerated when I scroll. So the first label might display Alabel with Elabel on top of it after has left the view and re-entered. I'm simply trying to create a single row of scrollable buttons (or labels for that matter). The collection view and cell were created via Storyboard. The code generates the correct number of cells in the CV, but the labels become layered when scrolled (horizontal).

```
let buttonLabels = ["Alabel", "Blabel", "Clabel", "Dlabel", "Elabel", "Flabel", "Glabel", "Hlabel", "Ilabel", "Jlabel", "Klabel", "Llabel", "Mlabel"]

@IBOutlet weak var btnCollVw: UICollectionView!

//loadColFlowLayout() is called from ViewDidLoad()
func loadColFlowLayout() { 
        let btnLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        btnLayout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirection.Horizontal
        btnLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 1, bottom: 0, right: 1)
        btnLayout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 63, height: 30)
        btnCollVw.collectionViewLayout = btnLayout
        btnCollVw!.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    }

func numberOfSections() -> Int {
       return 1
       }

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
      return buttonLabels.count
       }

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        var cell: UICollectionViewCell = self.iconCollVw.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("swIconsCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UICollectionViewCell

        var makeButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 63, 29))
        makeButton.setTitle(buttonLabels[indexPath.item], forState: .Normal)
        makeButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: .Normal)
        cell.addSubview(makeButton)
        // or using cell.contentView.addSubview(makeButton)

    return cell

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem in cell reusing, each time when you dequeue cell from collection view it can already has button, look at my a bit improved version when I check for button with known tag on cell:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    var cell: UICollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("swIconsCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UICollectionViewCell
    if cell.viewWithTag(1234) == nil {
        var makeButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 63, 29))
        makeButton.setTitle(buttonLabels[indexPath.item], forState: .Normal)
        makeButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: .Normal)
        makeButton.tag = 1234;
        cell.addSubview(makeButton)
        // or using cell.contentView.addSubview(makeButton)
    }
    return cell
}
```

you can do the same in another way for example create subclass of `UICollectionViewCell`

Comment: Many thanks! I had tried an if conditional, but not using a tag. There is still a bit of an issue as the code only generates on screen buttons. On the iPhone6 sim the buttons start over after 6 in portrait view, on an iPad simulator it generates the entire button list. The overlap issue is gone.